Whether the critical point of a meromorphic function lies in domain of convergence
Consider a meromorephic function $V(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\kappa_{l+1}z^{l}$, where $\kappa_{l}\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $l$'s. Then such function has a domain of convergence near 0. Suppose one can also analytic continuate it to certain bigger domain (still denoted as $V(z)$), and in particular, to the whole $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, where $V(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and $V^{'}(z_{c})=0$ for some $z_{c}>0$.
The question is do we have that $z_{c}$ lies in the domain of convergence of $V(z)$ at 0, i.e, is $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\kappa_{l+1}z_{c}^{l}$ a convergent series? If $\kappa_{l}$'s are all nonnegative, then certainly we see a critical point before the function goes to infinity, but I'm not sure what if there are infinite many $\kappa_{l}$'s that are negative. If this doesn't neccesarily hold, what other constriants we can add to make sure that it happens?
